# Conveying 'It's (not) coming home'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, sport

> The song [[Three Lions]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Lions) has been described as the de facto "anthem" of English football since 1996. Its chorus, with the refrain "**It's coming home**", has become a popular chant for fans at England games.

I was joking with a couple of French friends during the last minutes of the match France-England and I said.

> Il ne revient pas à la maison.

I am wondering if my wording was idiomatic enough.

> Il ne revient pas chez lui.

sounds not natural to my ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is idiomatic. Both of these sentences are actually failures. The very same failure this fake ad from the English tabloid "*[The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/20702002/the-sun-takes-over-paris-its-coming-home/)*" exhibits:

[image]

*Il rentre chez nous* doesn't mean the Cup come back home but "the player (Jude Bellingham) is coming back to our home", a double failure even.

The pronoun *it* represents the World Cup which happens to be a feminine word in French (***la** Coupe du monde*) so right and idiomatic translations could have been:

> ***Elle** ne revient pas chez **elle**.*

or

> ***Elle** ne rentre pas à la maison.*

while the original sentence would be:

> *Elle revient/rentre chez elle/à la maison*.